# How to get more accurate gps readings in android app?

Tags: android, android-location

Im using this code for getting the location for my app:

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000L, 200.0f, this);
```

But when i tried the app in my real android phone it show this location about 80 kilometers away from the location im actualy at.. How would i make this code more accurate.. I want the result to be way more accurate for what im making..

Im using the onLocationChanged to display it at the map.. Here it is:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if (location != null) {

        //Gets users longitude and latitude
        lat = location.getLatitude();
        lng = location.getLongitude();

        //sets the GeoPoint usersLocation equal lat and lng
        userLocation = new GeoPoint((int) lat * 1000000, (int) lng * 1000000);

        OverlayItem usersLocationIcon = new OverlayItem(userLocation, null, null);
        LocationPin myLocationPin = new LocationPin(userIcon, MainActivity.this);

        //Removes the previous location
        if(previousLocation != null)
               mainMap.getOverlays().remove(previousLocation); 

        myLocationPin.getLocation(usersLocationIcon);
        overlayList.add(myLocationPin);

        //refresh the map
        mainMap.invalidate(); 

        //Making myLocationPin into the previousLocation just to be able to remove it later
        previousLocation = myLocationPin;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The call `requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000L, 200.0f, this);` is asking to be updated no more than once every 1000ms when the location from GPS changes by more than 200.0 meters from the last update. If you want finer precision, try lowering these numbers.

However, you shouldn't be off by 80km. Are you testing this outside with a clear view of the sky?

I think the issue is with rounding. You are using `new GeoPoint((int) lat * 1000000, (int) lng * 1000000);`, but instead do this:

```
new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1e6), (int) (lng * 1e6));
```

The difference is, the double values were converted to integers before the multiplication. This way the multiplication happens afterwards, and so the digits after the decimal point are maintained.

Comment: The view of the sky is clear and i tried to lower the 1000ms into 500ms and the 200 meters into 50 meters.. But it still shows me 80km away from the location im realy at.. I also tried to start Google Maps and this shows the real location of me..

Comment: How are you showing the location in your app? If you log the latitude and longitude values and type them into Google Maps where does it put you?

Comment: Im using google maps API to display this longitude and latitude.

Comment: Could you edit your question with the code you use to do that?

Comment: I tried the app with a second phone and it did exactly the same thing.. It displays that im in a totaly other city than i am.

Comment: I edited my answer, please try fixing the rounding and see if that fixes it

Comment: I changed code to the 1e6 thingy and now i get error saying "The constructor GeoPint(double, double) is undentified

Comment: The important point is actually the parentheses around the multiplication. Make sure you cast the result of the multiplication to an integer like I show in the example.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible answers...

You can either ask for fine permission, this uses nearby wi-fi networks along with GPS in order to get a better track on where you are:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

or you might just be getting bad GPS data.  Have you tried to restart the phone?  Are you getting the correct location in Google Maps?

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did use this permission in the app.. And it does work perfectly in Google Maps.. But i can't see the problem.. Is there some code i can add to make it look for more accurate locations ?

Comment: what locations are you getting that are inaccurate? are they just string values, or is it something displayed in your app?